# How to start the c# FileSystemWatcher function indefinitely when executing the program?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I am developing windows program using .Net Framework.

I want to create a program that executes a function when a file is created in a specific folder using FileSystemWatcher.

Below is my code.

```
public async Task<int> CollectFunc() {
   string path = @"C:\test";
   try
   {
      FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
      {
      Path=path
      Filter="test.log"
      };
      watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(WatcherFunc);
      watcher.IncludeSubdrectories=true;
      watcher.EnableRaisingEvents=true;
   }
   catch
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Error");
   }
   

   while(true)
   {
      await Task.Delay(100000);
   }
}

public async void WatcherFunc(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
   Console.WriteLine("File Created: " + e.FullPath);
}
```

When I start the program, file creation is monitored until I close the program.

An example is shown below.

On September 1st, the following file is created.
C:\test\20200901\test.log
The program then prints "File Created: C:\test\20200901\test.log".

And on September 2nd
C:\test\20200902\test.log file is created,
The program will then output "File Created: C:\test\20200902\test.log".

...

But sometimes the Watcher doesn't work and I have to reboot the program.

Please let me know if there is any better or more stable logic than my source code.

I look forward to your kind reply.

Comment: Do you see any correlating factors when this happens? Like a lot of new files? Long time of no new files? ... anything?

Comment: Btw: you don't need to put the Task into a Spin-Wait. I'd rather call Console.ReadKey in the calling main or something like that.

Comment: @Fildor In my opinion, if the file is created quickly, or if an error occurs in WatcherFunc(), the watcher cannot be performed after that. Actually this is my opinion, I don't know the exact cause.

Comment: @Fildor The source code I wrote is an example. Actually, it runs on winform, not console.

Comment: By "quickly" you mean many files in short succession? Exception in the Handler: yes, I'd recommend to guard against Exceptions there by enclosing its contents with try/catch.

Comment: Ok, if it's winforms, then you do not need to block the task at all. Make the watcher a class field, though to prevent it from going out of scope and be collected.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, you are right. Many files are created in succession. There is a try/catch. Sorry. I will revise the source code again.

Comment: OK, in the current version, the _creation and setup_ of the watcher is in try/catch. What you need to add is a try/catch inside `WatcherFunc`. If something explodes there, it might blow up the watcher, too.

Comment: The FileSystemWatcher triggers the Event. This leads to the EventHandler `WatcherFunc` being called. Now, if _inside_ that function there is an exception, then this exception might bubble up into the watcher code and lead to it stop its service. So, just insert a "firewall" there. This has the benefit of logging errors / unwanted behavior in your handler code, too.

Comment: @Fildor I understand. Does the filesystemwatcher explode if an error occurs inside the WatcherFunc?

Does this stabilize the logic of the above source code? I don't think it's stable because of while.

Comment: @Fildor Can you tell me what a "firewall" is?

Comment: I didn't mean a literal "firewall". Just a try/catch, so exceptions won't bubble up to the caller of the event handler and leave that part in an inconsistent/unknown state. Even if you do nothing more than log the exception, the FileSystemWatcher can go on to function properly after.

Comment: _"I don't think it's stable because of while._" Yes, make the FileSystemWatcher reference a class field and get rid of that while loop entirely. ... I think I could have written an answer by now :/

Comment: @Fildor I really appreciate it.!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these changes:

```
// Introduce a class field, to prevent the watcher reference from going out of scope.
private FileSystemWatcher watcher = null;

public void CollectFunc() { // no need for async any more ...
   string path = @"C:\test";
   try
   {
      // Init class field
      watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
      {
      Path=path
      Filter="test.log"
      };
      watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(WatcherFunc);
      watcher.IncludeSubdrectories=true;
      watcher.EnableRaisingEvents=true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // Better know what the problem actually was.
      Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
   }
   
   // It's a winforms app - we don't need to block this => away with while(true)
}

public async void WatcherFunc(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) 
{
   // Just in case, catch and log exceptions
   try{
       Console.WriteLine("File Created: " + e.FullPath);
   } catch( Exception ex ) {
      // TODO: Log Exception or handle it.
   }
}
```

On top of that: It is a known issue, that a high number and frequency of changes can lead to some buffer to overflow in the watcher (if that still applies, but I remember running into this some years ago).

The **problem with buffer overflow** is mentioned here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize?view=netcore-3.1#remarks

It may also be worthwhile to register a handler to the `Error` event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.error?view=netcore-3.1

I guess that your `Console.WriteLine` in the event handler is just an example code and you are actually doing more than that. In the past, I found that it releaves stress from the FileSystemWatcher's buffer if I keep code very small here and handle the event as quickly as possible.

So, what I did was enqueue the file path in a qeue and have that queue handled on a different thread. This ensures that event are handled as quickly as possible while not losing any. Peeks can be caught by the queue getting bigger and be dealt with independently by another thread. In other words: Things pile up *outside* the watcher's buffers.

Comment: [https://code-examples.net/en/q/5e5cb3](https://code-examples.net/en/q/5e5cb3)
I found this.

Comment: Doesn't look too bad. At least he can _detect_ buffer overflow and recover from it. You may want to get "inspired" a little by this. But this doesn't address the _cause_ being the overflows happening. This can only be improved (not totally remedied, I'd say) by keeping the watchers buffers low as described in the last paragraph in my answer.